# Linker error on const values

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to create some string constants so I have the following:

**Constants.h**

```
extern NSString* const CONSTANT_ONE;
```

**Constants.m**

```
NSString *const CONSTANT_ONE = @"CONSTANT_ONE";
```

**SomeOtherFile.m**

```
#import "Constants.h"
... snip
NSString* something = CONSTANT_ONE;
```

Constants.m is listed in the "Compile Sources" bit of the target's build phases and is a member of the target when I look in its "Target Membership" section of the sidebar.

When I try to compile I get an error like:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CONSTANT_ONE", referenced from:
      -[SomeOtherFile someMethod:] in SomeOtherFile.o
```

I think I might be misunderstanding something basic here - can anyone help me with this error please?

Comment: What you have here looks correct. Linker errors can be difficult to track down. Can you post some of the actual files in question so we can better help you?

Answer (score 1):

The code in my initial question was correct. I don't know why but simply closing and re-opening Xcode solved the problem and it built fine. Just Xcode getting itself confused.